# How to use RhinoMocks Test GetEntityByName<T> Function? Is it possible or good practice?

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, generics, reflection, rhino-mocks

I have a method using reflection to get a generic type of entity by name.

```
public T GetEntity<T>( string name ) where T : EntityBase
{
    return GetDbSet<T>().FirstOrDefault( x => x.Name == name );
}
public class EntityBase : IEntityBase
{
    [Key]
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

And there are lots of entities that inherit from `EntityBase`.

Can someone please shed some light on how to use RhinoMocks to test this method and similar methods with a generic type and reflection? Or is it a good idea to test these kinds of methods?

Comment: You would have to mock GetDBSet.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, the problem for me is how to deal with generic T. If there are 20 entities inherit from EntityBase, do I have to write 20 tests?

Comment: Only if you have behavior that is specific for a given T.  Otherwise, just inject an EntityBase mock.  Also, if the method under test is an Entity Framework method, I wouldn't bother testing it.  Rely instead on your integration tests to verify proper functionality.

Comment: @RobertHarvey it is EF behind. and couldn't find any proper way to test it other than loop through all entities, and it seems pointless... I think I have to leave it now. thanks for your help.

Comment: @WinterWinter Where is the reflection in your example? Can you please show an implementaytion of `GetDbSet<T>()` method?